# Console is missing my-user@

Tags: command-line

I've just received a new Ubuntu server at work, however, when logging in via the terminal I'm missing the my-user@server-name in the console. Also, I'm not able to use TAB for finished of folder-names etc.

Looking at my user-folder, there's no files in it (no .profile, .bashrc etc.).

As I don't have any idea why this is happening, I'm not able to Google for similar issues.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should have those files in `/etc/skel` (check with `ls -la /etc/skel`). If so you can copy the files you need (and change them if you need so)

Comment: I've copied the files from /etc/skel and changed user/group to my user/group. However, it does not seem to change anything? Should I restart the server or log-in/out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy system default files by using following command

```
cp -v /etc/skel/.bash* /etc/skel/.profile ~/
```

For Better my-user@server PS1 Prompt add folloing lines in your .bashrc

```
# When Commands Fail Turn PS1 In RED
PS1="\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[34m\]^_^[\u@\h:\w]\\$ \[\e[0m\]; else echo \[\e[31m\]O_O[\u@\h:\w]\\$ \[\e[0m\]; fi\`"
```

More Details: [.bashrc](https://github.com/MiteshShah/DotFiles/blob/master/Backtrack5/.bashrc)